# Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2008 Application Bug Reporting Website

Tags: tfs, tfs-2008

Is there a good application that ties into TFS to allow users of your application to submit bug reports or software change requests?

Are there any good 3rd party applications that tie into TFS using the provided API?  I would like to good application to submit bugs to and then assign them to people in TFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Work Item Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx) (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080913224531/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx)) allows users without a TFS CAL to submit and view their own work items (bug reports or change requests).

Or if your users have a CAL, they can use [Team System Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980951.aspx) (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090725081901/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980951.aspx)) and will be able to view work items from other users too.

If this doesn't answer your question, can you clarify what you mean by an application that ties in with TFS.